# Python, FDB - Firebird timeout

Tags: python, timeout, firebird, fdb

I'm writing a small script with python and the module fdb (http://pythonhosted.org//fdb/index.html) which reads data from a firebird database and then writes it into a postgres database. (With psycopg2 module)

Everything works fine except one thing,
If I have a query from the firebird database and the connection breaks the program hangs because there is no timeout.

I have searched the fdb documentation but there is no option for it.

How i could add a timeout to my sql queries?
or what would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: Firebird itself doesn't have query timeouts.

Comment: Is this not related to firebird driver for python,the delphi and c# drivers report disconect errors

Answer (score 0):

Since Firebird 4.0, Firebird has [statement timeouts](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/4_0/rlsnotes40.html#rnfb40-stmnt-timeouts). Statement timeouts can be configured on three levels:

- Database-level, in `firebird.conf` and/or `databases.conf` with setting `StatementTimeout` (timeout in seconds). This establishes the upper-level of a timeout (that means, timeouts on session or statement levels can be lower, but higher values will be ignored)
- Session-level, using the statement [`SET STATEMENT TIMEOUT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-management-setstatementtimeout), which will configure the *default* timeout for statements in the current session (connection).
- Statement-level, using the low-level API. As far as I know, this isn't exposed in [FDB](https://pypi.org/project/fdb/) nor in its successor, [firebird-driver](https://pypi.org/project/firebird-driver/).

That said, the statement timeout settings will not protect against broken connections.